# Change the order of totals

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm having some troubles figuring out how to change the order of the totals in the transactional email templates (In Magento).

Basicly I want the 'Tax' row to be at the very bottom - below 'Grand total incl. tax'.

I know that this is the code, that prints the rows. But I can't seem to figure out how to change the order of the rows.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
<?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
<?php else:?>
<tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
    <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
        <?php else:?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
    <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
        <?php else:?>
        <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif?>
```

Could anyone be of help with this problem?

Thanks and have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Method 1: Modifying the theme template file.

Copy `app/design/frontend/base/sales/order/totals.phtml` to your theme file and open it.
Add the following to the top of it.

```
if($tax = $this->getTotal('tax'))
{
    $this->removeTotal('tax');
    $this->addTotal($tax, 'grand_total');
}
```

This code will remove the tax from the totals list, then re-add it below the Grand Total.  You should move the totals.phtml file into your custom theme folder so upgrades won't override it.

## Method 2: Overriding the core block file.

You can do the same patch by overriding the core Totals block by doing the following:

1. Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php`
2. Open `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php` and change the `getTotals()` function to the following:

   ```
   public function getTotals($area=null)
   {
           //Move tax below grand_total
           if($tax = $this->getTotal('tax'))
           {
           $this->removeTotal('tax');
           $this->addTotal($tax, 'grand_total');
           }       

           $totals = array();
           if ($area === null) {
           $totals = $this->_totals;
           } else {
           $area = (string)$area;
           foreach ($this->_totals as $total) {
               $totalArea = (string) $total->getArea();
               if ($totalArea == $area) {
                   $totals[] = $total;
               }
           }
       }       
       return $totals;
   }
   ```

Comment: <td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>> I want update colspan value here. Can you please help.